# Copy Text out of div container without button

Tags: javascript, html, text, copy

I am trying to copy the Text out of this div container by clicking on the div itself. I don't want to add a Button.

```
<div class="code">
    <a>Hello</a>
    <img src="img/copy.png" alt="CSGO" />
</div>
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? By "Copy" you mean add in the clipboard or duplicate it?

Comment: copy to clipboard, haven't really tried anything since my javascript skills are limited :/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onclick`

```
<div class="code" onclick='copy()'>
    <a id='code'>Codes</a>
</div>
```

And JavaScript

```
function copy(){
  let div_value = document.getElementById('code').text
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(div_value);
}
```

It  will copy text in element with id "code" to clipboard.

```js
function copy(){
  let div_value = document.getElementById('code').text
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(div_value);
  alert('Text '+div_value+' was copied to clipboard!')
}
```

```html
<div class="code" onclick='copy()'>
    <a id='code'>Codes</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a click handler to any html element.

```
document.querySelector(".code").addEventListener("click", your_function);
```

`your_function` can then grab what you want from the div element and add it treat the content like a copy if you want.

Comment: I get what you are trying to tell me but I don't know to to grab anything with the your_function :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, you can find comments in the snippet :)

```js
function copy(el) {
  // Create a dummy element
  var inputText = document.createElement('input')
  document.body.appendChild(inputText);

  // Put the value in your dummy input
  inputText.value = el.querySelector("a").text;

  // You can use select on inputs
  inputText.select();

  // Copy the "selected" text
  document.execCommand("copy");

  console.log("Copied: " + inputText.value);
  
  // Remove your dummy input
  inputText.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="code" onclick="copy(this)">
  <a>Hello</a>
  <img src="img/copy.png" alt="CSGO" />
</div>

<div class="code" onclick="copy(this)">
  <a>A different text</a>
  <img src="img/copy.png" alt="CSGO" />
</div>

<div class="code" onclick="copy(this)">
  <a>Still works</a>
  <img src="img/copy.png" alt="CSGO" />
</div>
```